# Decomposition and valuation rings

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, absolute-value

I am reading *Algebraic Number Theory by A. Fröhlich, M. J. Taylor*, it first introduced the theory:

> *$(K,u)$ be a field and its absolute value, $(K_u,\bar u)$ be its completion and absolute value extension, $L/K$ a finite separable field extension.*
>
> *Then the $K_u$-algebra $K_u\otimes_K L \approx \prod_i (K_u\otimes_K L)\eta_i \approx \prod_{w_i} L_{w_{i}}$.*
>
> *( $\eta_i$'s are idempotents of $K_u\otimes_K L$, $L_{w_i}$'s are finite separable field extension of $K_u$ where $w_i$ runs through all absolute values of L which extend u.)*

I have no problem with this theory, my question is the next proposition:

> *With the same notation above, let $\mathfrak p$ be a prime ideal of a Dedekind domain $\mathfrak o$ with field of fraction $K$, and if $u$ is a discrete absolute value of $K$ corresponding to $\mathfrak p$, then, writing $\mathfrak o_{K_u}$ for the valuation ting in $K_u$($\mathfrak o_{K_u}=\{x;\bar u(x)\leqslant 1\}$), we have $\mathfrak o_{K_u}\otimes_{\mathfrak o_K} \mathfrak o_L \approx  \prod_i (\mathfrak o_{K_u}\otimes_{\mathfrak o_K} \mathfrak o_L)\eta_i \approx \prod_{w_i} \mathfrak o_{L_{w_i}}$*

The book doesn't specify what $\mathfrak o_L, \mathfrak o_K, \mathfrak o_{L_{w_i}}$ are, but with the convention notations in the book, it might mean valuation rings in $L, K, L_{w_i}$ respectively.

However, since $L$ has multiple distinct absolute values ($w_i$'s), it's not clear $\mathfrak o_L$ corresponds to which absolute value of $L$, hence I have no idea what this property is talking about. What are $\mathfrak o_L, \mathfrak o_{w_i}$?

This is its proof which may help understanding:
[image]

(1.3 in the proof is here)
[image]

(u-norm definition)
[image]

Comment: The ring $\def\O{{\mathfrak o}} \O_K$ is   $\O$, where $\O$ is the Dedekind domain of the question - secretly, the author is surely thinking the ring of integers of $K$, where $K$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb Q$, even if it need not be necessarily so.  The ring $\O_L$ is the integral closure of $\O_K$ in $L$, and is therefore a Dedekind domain itself (a theorem of Dedekind, presumably). The rings $\O_{w_i}$ are the valuation rings of the $L_{w_i}$, as in the previous proposition.  (cont)

Comment: (cont)  BTW - the 'ring of integers' of a number field $K$ is by definition the integral closure of the $\mathbb Z$ in $K$, and by the parenthetical theorem of Dedekind above, a Dedekind domain itself.

Comment: @peterag Thanks a lot, that solves my question. BTW, can $\mathfrak o_{K_u}\otimes_{\mathfrak o_K} \mathfrak o_L$ be embedded in $K_u \otimes_K L$? It seems it does so in the proof, since it defines a norm on $K_u \otimes_K L$ and claim $\mathfrak o_{K_u}\otimes_{\mathfrak o_K} \mathfrak o_L$ is closed under such norm. (Though I don't know if it means that yet.)

Comment: Yes: $\def\O{{\mathfrak o}} \O_{K_u}\otimes_{\O_K}\O_L   \subset  \O_{K_u}\otimes_{\O_K} L = \O_{K_u}\otimes_{\O_K} K \otimes_K L = K_u \otimes_K L$. (The inclusion at the beginning is an inclusion because the second module is localisation (non-zero elements of $\O_L$) of the first, and the first module has no $\O_L$ torsion).

Comment: @peterag You really helped me a lot, somehow I am too tired to think about it now (It's over midnight here in my time zone), so I will try comprehend some details tomorrow. Here is a big picture problem, is this proof trying to define $\parallel . \parallel$, and then use its defining topology to get both "dense" and "closed" part?

Comment: If I understand: the right hand side of the isomorphism - call it $\phi$ - above $K_u\otimes_K L  \approx \prod_{w_i} L_{w_{i}}$is endowed with the product topology - in which, by  the CRT, (the image of) $\def\O{{\mathfrak o}}\phi(\O_L)$ is dense. (No talk of norms needed.)  Now, the product topology on the right  arises from the norm  $ \def\N#1{\parallel#1 \parallel}\N\cdot_r$ defined as  the sum (component-wise) of the $w_i$-norms, which is a $u$-norm. (cont)

Comment: (cont)The topology on the left can also be given by a $u $-norm $\N\cdot$- which is as defined above. But we can use the isomorphism $\phi$ to define another $u$-define on the left (define $ \N{x}_l =\N{\phi(x)}_r $). By 1.3 the induced topologies on the left are the same. Hence the closed set on the left maps onto (since it is dense) the closed set on the right.